# Jquery changes position of div/img

Tags: jquery, image, html, positioning

I have found a workaround to center a large image (no background) in a smaller div.

```
#pic {
 width: 60%;
 height: 349px;
 float:right;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}

#pic img {
 left:50%;
 margin-left: -100%;
 position:relative;
}
```

I am happy with the positioning.

However, once I use the Jquery cycle plugin, it completely messes up the positioning and size of the images.

As when I inspect the element (With DOM inspector), it the following values are striked through:

<strike>left:50%;</strike>

<strike>margin-left: -100%;</strike>

This is causing the repositioning.

Why are they all in the sudden not valid anymore after using Jquery and how can I fix this?

Thank you for any help!

Scott

Comment: I don't know the cycle plugin... but it looks like it is overwriting the values of these css properties. Maybe the plugin offers some customization where you can set these values manually.

Comment: The plugin most likely comes with a css file, that is most likely overriding your css.

Comment: this is the plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/basic.html but there is no CSS with it. Can a .js file affect the CSS settings?

Comment: Yes, the plugin (javascript) will actually be affecting the styles you set. It functions by affecting the DOM directly on events such as (in this case) mouse overs. Affecting these properties is actually how the plugin achieves its desired effects. Have a look at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/adv.html, especially the cssFirst option. i haven't used this personally, but may be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add !important in the css

```
 #pic {
 width: 60% !important;
 height: 349px;
 float:right;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
#pic img { 
left:50%;
 margin-left: -100% !important;
 position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That actually works! However I will try to use a different Jquery now which does not affect the CSS in the first place - lets see and Thank you!

Comment: Anybody any idea if there is actually a jquery script which does not affect my CSS settings?